# jquery ajax is giving the same result to all divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to be able to rename files. At the moments its working but, 
for example lets say i have:

file one name is 'hello', file two name is 'bye', file three name is 'hey'

and i rename file one to 'something' it will rename it, but if i then rename file two to 'youarecool' it will rename file one and two that.

here is my javascript, what am i doing wrong. here is my jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/RSvre/

here is the html for each of the files

```
 <div class="each_file">
         <span class="file_icon"><img src="img/file-icon/avi.png" /></span>
         <div class="file_details">
            <div class="file_title"><a class="fnl" href="#">filename</a></div>
               <div class="file_detail_stat">filesize | downloads Downloads | 
                Uploaded on   date</div>
               </div>
           <ul class="file_manage_icons">
               <li><a href="#">
               <span title="Email" class="mail" id="$auth"></span>
               </a></li>
               <li><a href="#"><span title="Edit" class="edit" id="$auth"></span></a></li>
               <li><a href="#"><span title="Lock" class="lock" id="$auth"></span></a></li>
               <li><a href="#"><span title="Delete" class="bin" id="$auth">
               </span></a> </li>
            </ul>
          <div class="clear"></div>
         </div>
```

and this is the javascript

```
$('.edit').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var auth = $(this).attr('id');
    var each = $(this).closest('.each_file').find('.fnl');

    $.post( "ajax/edit_filename.php", { auth:auth })
       .done(function( data ) {

        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
          modal: true,
          resizable: false,
          title: 'Edit file name',
          buttons: {
              "Close": function() {
                  $(this).dialog("destroy");
                  $(this).dialog("close");
              }
          } 
        });
        $('.ui-dialog-content').html('<input type="text" class="newfname" value="'+data+'"/><div class="btn_l"><input type="submit" class="submit_btn" id="edit_filenameb" value="Edit Name" /></div>');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#edit_filenameb', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var nname = $('.newfname').val();
        console.log(nname);

        if(nname == ''){
            $('.submit_btn').effect('shake');
        } else {
            $.post('ajax/change_filename.php', {nname:nname, auth:auth})
            .done(function(data){
                each.text(data);
                $('#dialog').dialog('close');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'd like to see your code that actually renames the file.

Comment: i dont think its the php which is the problem. Because if i just re name 1 file then it works fine. But if i rename a different file then it will rename all the files the same..

Comment: here is the jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net/RSvre/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that each time you rename a file, you add a new click listener to `document`, but you never clean it up. When you rename the next one it actually calls both rename functions. You could save the name of the file to be renamed in a variable, and then in a single click listener set on page load rename the file. Also you'd have to have a way to tell if the renaming has already occurred so that it won't be called on every page click.

Comment: thanks, yeah ill have another play around with it and see what i can come up with

Comment: you were correct, i removed the $(document) to $('#edit_filenameb').click(function(e){ and it works now. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap out your inner click binding, so you'd have:

```
$('.edit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var auth = $(this).attr('id');
    var each = $(this).closest('.each_file').find('.fnl');

    $.post( "ajax/edit_filename.php", { auth:auth })
       .done(function( data ) {

        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
          modal: true,
          resizable: false,
          title: 'Edit file name',
          buttons: {
              "Close": function() {
                  $(this).dialog("destroy");
                  $(this).dialog("close");
              }
          } 
        });
        $('.ui-dialog-content').html('<input type="text" class="newfname" value="'+data+'"/><div class="btn_l"><input type="submit" class="submit_btn" id="edit_filenameb" value="Edit Name" /></div>');
    });

    //Code from here took to outside
});

//This was taken out from the other click binding
$(document).on('click', '#edit_filenameb', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var nname = $('.newfname').val();
    var auth = ... //Get the auth here
    console.log(nname);

    if(nname == ''){
        $('.submit_btn').effect('shake');
    } else {
        $.post('ajax/change_filename.php', {nname:nname, auth:auth})
        .done(function(data){
            each.text(data);
            $('#dialog').dialog('close');
        });
    }
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: i tryed that am added some more code to get the correct .fnl but now its making all the titles the same

Comment: its coming for the ui.dialog-content html