# javascript works on jsfiddle but not on my browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know this is strange but i have a jsfiddle which works fine but when i use it in my browser the 'edit name' button is not being triggered

the only difference between my browser code and the code i made in jsfiddle is that iv added ajax, but that is not the problem

here is my javascript

```
$('.edit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var auth = $(this).attr('id');
    var each = $(this).closest('.each_file').find('.fnl');
    $.post( "ajax/edit_filename.php", {
        auth:auth
    })
    .done(function( data ) {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            title: 'Edit file name',
            buttons: {
                "Close": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("destroy");
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            } 
        });
        $('.ui-dialog-content').html('<input type="text" class="newfname" value="'+data+'"/><div class="btn_l"><input type="submit" class="submit_btn" id="edit_filenameb" value="Edit Name" /></div>');
    });
    $('#edit_filenameb').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var nname = $('.newfname').val();
        console.log(nname);
        if(nname == ''){
            $('.submit_btn').effect('shake');
        } else {
            $.post('ajax/change_filename.php', {
                nname:nname, 
                auth:auth
            })
            .done(function(data){
                each.text(data);
                $('#dialog').dialog('close');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

and the jsfiddle is here, http://jsfiddle.net/RSvre/

Comment: Did you remember to a) include jQuery and b) wrap your code in a document ready call OR place the code at the end of the document?

Comment: Then have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Since we don't know what you did on your page, and hence cannot reproduce the problem, we cannot really help you. [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) and do some debugging on your own.

Comment: yeah iv checked and nothing come up, iv changed $('#edit_filenameb').click(function(e){ too $('document').on('click', '#edit_filenameb', function(e){ and it triggers the button but it makes all filenames that instead of just the one im editing

Comment: Can you update your question with the minimum HTML / JS needed to reproduce your issue?

Comment: its all here, i thought i fixed it because the jsfiddle worked but now iv tryed it in my browser it didnt. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21079763/jquery-ajax-is-giving-the-same-result-to-all-divs

Comment: I wonder about trying $('#edit_filenameb').on('click', function(e){...
I often have problems with dynamically generated html, and I wonder if .dialog is treated like that.

Comment: can you please give me your page link

Answer (score 1):

i sorted this, i ended up just redoing the full code and i use $.ajax instead of $.post and in worked